# How to display page title in the contact form?

Tags: wordpress, contact-form-7

I'm using a contact form 7 for the contact forms. I have a page for a doctor for example, and it has it's own form on the same page. How can I display the title of that page into the input field or select field on the contact form 7?

I did some research for dynamic data on contact form 7 and I found this https://wordpress.org/plugins/contact-form-7-dynamic-text-extension/

I put the following code into the form but it's not retrieving the page title:

```
[dynamictext dynamicname “CF7_get_post_var key=’title'”]
```

Any help is very much appreciated.

Comment: Try this https://wordpress.org/support/topic/how-to-pass-the-title-of-the-post-and-send-it-to-me-in-email/

Answer (score 2):

To use shortcode inside the wpcf7 forms, an easy way is "Berenis" solution, but with an important change.
Instead of `add_shortcode( 'cf7_extra_fields', 'cf7_extra_fields_func' );` should be `wpcf7_add_shortcode( 'cf7_extra_fields', 'cf7_extra_fields_func', true );`.

Remaining code can be same, on functions.php:

```
wpcf7_add_shortcode( 'cf7_extra_fields', 'cf7_extra_fields_func', true );
function cf7_extra_fields_func( $atts ) {
   $html = '';
   $html .= '<input type="hidden" name="page-title" value="'.get_the_title().'" />';
   $html .= '<input type="hidden" name="page-url" value="'.get_the_permalink().'" />';
   return $html;
}
```

On contact form, use: [cf7_extra_fields], on email fields use: [page-title] and [page-url].

This worked for me, without any issues.

Answer (score 2):

a year late, but I just saw it. I suppose you have already solved it. The error is because the shortcode has wrong characters. The correct thing is like this:

```
[dynamictext dynamicname "CF7_get_post_var key='title'"]
```

Regards!

Answer (score 1):

Put this to functions.php

```
add_shortcode( 'cf7_extra_fields', 'cf7_extra_fields_func' );
function cf7_extra_fields_func( $atts ) {
    $html = '';
    $html .= '<input type="hidden" name="page-title" value="<'.get_the_title().'">';
    $html .= '<input type="hidden" name="page-url" value="<'.get_the_permalink().'">';
    return $html;
}
```

Then when editing contact form add this shortcode inside `[cf7_extra_fields]`
When passing form fields to email use `[page-title]` and `[page-url]`
No plugin needed

Answer (score 0):

Did you try with jquery/js ? like `jQuery("#field_id").val("<?php echo get_the_title(); ?>");` . you can try this code in the page where the form is using.

Comment: Is there a way only inside the contact form 7 or inside page from CMS without having to edit the backend? because there will be like more than 10 pages with different forms

Comment: The plugin you have tried is providing such options,please read its description.
CF7_get_post_var key=’title’ <– retrieves the Post’s Title
CF7_get_post_var key=’slug’ <– retrieves the Post’s Slug